# Matplotlib: TypeError: can't draw a chart

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer and I am trying to fit a linear line of best fit to my matplotlib graph. I keep getting the error that x and y do not have the same first dimension. Does anyone know that how to solve this error?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
for z in range(0, 10100, 100):
    p = 1013 * pow((1 - ((z/1000) / 45.846)),5.263)
    x = np.linspace(0, 10000, 101)
    print(z,round(p,3))
    plt.plot(p,x)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you really want `plot` and `show` to be in the `for` loop?  What do you believe the dimensions of `p` to be?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `p` is just a number, you may have wanted to append it to a list. Moreover, the plot has to be outside the loop. Here you have a working example:

```
p = []
for z in range(0, 10100, 100):
    y = 1013 * pow((1 - ((z/1000) / 45.846)),5.263)
    p.append(y)
    x = np.linspace(0, 10000, 101)
plt.plot(p,x)
plt.show()
```